# How can I transform a quadratic into an factored equation?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I transform a quadratic polynomial in x and y into an equation of the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c$?

```
f = -9 x + (3 x^2)/4 + (3 y^2)/4;
```

[Completing the Square](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletingtheSquare.html)

```
CompleteSquare[f_, x_] :=
  Module[{a, b, c},
    {c, b, a} = CoefficientList[f, x];  
    a (x + b/2/a)^2 + Simplify[(c - b^2/4/a)]]

CompleteSquare[f, x]

(*
    3/4 (-6 + x)^2 + 3/4 (-36 + y^2)
*)
```

What I want is the following:

```
(x - 6)^2 + y^2 == 36
```

Answer (score 2):

```
coeffs[expr_, vars_]:= Flatten[CoefficientList[expr, vars]]

CompleteSquare[expr_, {x_, y_}]:= Module[{a, b, c, c1, c2, eqns, sols}, 
    eqns = Thread[coeffs[c1 (x - a)^2 + c2 (y - b)^2 - c, {x, y}] - coeffs[f, {x, y}] == 0];
    Check[sols = Solve[eqns, {a, b, c, c1, c2}], Return@$Failed];
    (x - a)^2 + c2/c1 (y - b)^2 == c/c1 /. sols
]
```

Now for the specific example.

```
f = -9 x + (3 x^2)/4 + (3 y^2)/4;
CompleteSquare[f, {x, y}]

(*{(-6 + x)^2 + y^2 == 36}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let first make the `CompleteSquare[f_, x_]` function according to your reference.

```
(* Destination Function = X1(x) = A*(x-B)^2, X2 = C  such that X1+X2 = f *)

CompleteSquare[f_, x_] := Module[{a, b, c}, 
{c, b, a} = Table[Coefficient[f, x, i], {i, 0, 2}]; X1 = a (x + b/(2 a))^2;
X2 = (c - b^2/(4 a)); Print[X1, "+" X2]]
```

When you run `CompleteSquare[f, x]` it will create `X1` and `X2` which will have the perfect square and additive part and `Print` their sum. For your example

```
f = -9 x + (3 x^2)/4 + (3 y^2)/4;

CompleteSquare[f, x]
X1
X2
```

And your desired equation is `X1 + X2 == 0`.

Comment: You really shouldn't define functions in a way that they modify external variables!!